# PHP Json encoding integers as strings

Tags: php, arrays, json, type-conversion

A user inputs values into a form on a Raspberry Pi and this should, in theory, convert the values to json format, write it to file, kill all of my bp sessions and start again (with a redirect to BBC as confirmation for now).

The parameters `tail`, `growthrate`, and `fps` are being encoded as **strings**, not **integers**. The result in the final file (`webtest1.json`) is that they appear as `"tail": "1"` and I need `"tail": 1`.

```
// check if a form was submitted
if( !empty( $_POST ) ){
    // convert form data to json format
    $postArray = array(
      "driver" => $_POST['driver'],
      "animation" => array(
        "typename" => $_POST["typename"],
        "tail" => $_POST["tail"],
        "growthRate" => $_POST["growthRate"]
      ),
      "run" => array(
        "fps" => $_POST["fps"]
      ),
      "layout" => $_POST['layout']  
    );
    //you might need to process any other post fields you have..

    $json = json_encode( $postArray );
    // make sure there were no problems
    //if( json_last_error() != JSON_ERROR_NONE ){
        //exit;  // do your error handling here instead of exiting
    // }
    $file = '/home/pi/Documents/webtest1.json';
    // write to file
    //   note: _server_ path, NOT "web address (url)"!
    file_put_contents( $file, $json);
}   
shell_exec("sudo killall bp");
shell_exec("sudo bp /home/pi/Documents/webtest1.json > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
header("Location: http://www.bbc.co.uk");
die();
```

Comment: version of your php?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the *number* `pi`.

Answer (score 4):

**Way 1:** If you have PHP version **5.3.3** or **greater** you can try like this with 2nd argument `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` to [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function without casting each and every numeric values. **Need less change if you've newest php version.**

Say your array is like this,

```
$arr = array(
    "driver" => 'driver',
    "animation" => array(
        "typename" => 'typename',
        "tail" => '1',
        "growthRate" => 10
    ),
    "run" => array(
        "fps" => '23'
    ),
    "layout" => 'layout'   
);

echo json_encode( $arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK );
```

**Output:**

```
 {  
   "driver":"driver",
   "animation":{  
      "typename":"typename",
      "tail":1,
      "growthRate":10
   },
   "run":{  
      "fps":23
   },
   "layout":"layout"
}
```

**Way 2:** Cast your each and every `$_POST` variable values to integer type like `(int)$_POST['fps']`. Also do it where you needed like for `fps`, `tail` or `growthRate` values. **This is good one but it may need to change many places on your code.**

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to stop it because I can't see your web form. But, you can use intVal to convert to integer any string. 
as in

```
 "tail" => intVal($_POST["tail"]),
```

I think that specifying type='number' on the input field might help with submitted values. worth a try

Answer (score 1):

What @Ian Middelkamp said.

But I would add you can use `(int)` casting too So stealing that example

```
"tail" => (int)$_POST["tail"],
```